# Тем самым - выделяется ли запятыми?

Tags: тем

"... показали результат, повысив тем самым доходность фонда."
Нужно ли выделять запятыми "тем самым"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не нужно запятых: это смысловой аналог местоимения "этим".